# Using Recursive feature while Flattening in Snowflake

Tags: json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, json-flattener

I have a JSON string, which needs to be parsed in order to retrieve particular values.Here is an example I am working with;

```
{
  "assignable_type": "SHIPMENT",
  "rule": {
    "rules": [
      {
        "meta_data": {},
        "rules": [
          {
            "op": "IN",
            "target": "CLIENT_FID",
            "type": "ARRAY_VALUE_ASSERTION",
            "values": [
              "flx::core:client:dbid/64171",
              "flx::core:client:dbid/76049",
              "flx::core:client:dbid/34040",
              "flx::core:client:dbid/61806"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "type": "AND"
      }
    ],
    "type": "OR"
  },
  "type": "USER_DEFINED"
}
```

The goal is to get the values when `"target":"CLIENT_FID"`.

**Expected Output** for this JSON file should be  ;

```
["flx::core:client:dbid/64171",
   "flx::core:client:dbid/76049",
   "flx::core:client:dbid/34040",
   "flx::core:client:dbid/61806"]
```

Here, as we can see `rules` is a list of dictionaries, and we can have nested lists as seen in the example.

Similarly, we have other JSON file of following type;

```
{
  "assignable_type": "SHIPMENT",
  "rule": {
    "rules": [
      {
        "meta_data": {},
        "rules": [
          {
            "op": "IN",
            "target": "PORT_OF_ENTRY_FID",
            "type": "ARRAY_VALUE_ASSERTION",
            "values": [
              "flx::core:port:dbid/566788",
              "flx::core:port:dbid/566931",
              "flx::core:port:dbid/561482"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "type": "AND"
      },
      {
        "meta_data": {},
        "rules": [
          {
            "op": "IN",
            "target": "PORT_OF_LOADING_FID",
            "type": "ARRAY_VALUE_ASSERTION",
            "values": [
              "flx::core:port:dbid/561465"
            ]
          },
          {
            "op": "IN",
            "target": "SHIPMENT_MODE",
            "type": "ARRAY_VALUE_ASSERTION",
            "values": [
              0
            ]
          },
          {
            "op": "IN",
            "target": "CLIENT_FID",
            "type": "ARRAY_VALUE_ASSERTION",
            "values": [
              "flx::core:client:dbid/28169"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "type": "AND"
      }
    ],
    "type": "OR"
  },
  "type": "USER_DEFINED"
}
```

For the second example ,

**Expected Output** shd be;

```
 ["flx::core:client:dbid/28169"]
```

As. seen, we may need to read the values at different depths in the file. In order to address this issue, I used following code;

```
/* first convert the string to a JSON object in cte1 */


with cte1 as (
select to_json(json_string) as json_rep,
      parse_json(json_extract_path_text(json_rep, 'rule.rules')) as list_elem

from table 1),

cte2 as (select split_array,
     json_extract_path_text(split_array, 'target') as target_client

 from (
select json_rep,
       list_elem, 
       t.value as split_array,
       typeof(split_array) as obj_type,
       index
     
from cte1,
     table(flatten(cte1.list_elem, recursive=>true)) as t) temp /* use recursive feature */

where split_array ilike '%"target":"client_fid"%' /* filter for those rows containing this string */ 
     and obj_type='OBJECT')

select 
        split_array,
        json_extract_path_text(split_array, 'values') as client_values
        
 from cte2
 where target_client='CLIENT_FID'; /* filter the rows where we have the dictionary containing client fid */
```

In order to address the issue of varying depth at which `client_fid` is found we're recursing while flattening the string into rows. The output which is obtained for both of above inputs is provided below,

For the first String we get the **actual** output in variable `client_values` as

```
["flx::core:client:dbid/64171",
           "flx::core:client:dbid/76049",
           "flx::core:client:dbid/34040",
           "flx::core:client:dbid/61806"]
```

Similarly, for the second string we get the **actual** output as

```
["flx::core:client:dbid/28169"]
```

As seen the code seems to be working in getting the correct output, but the way I filtered in the final query for `target_client='CLIENT_FID';` it seems to be a very hacky way. Hence is it possible to get a better approach to resolve the issue of retrieving client fid values though the depth can vary in the given input.

Help is appreciated.